# Descrbing solutions of $\sin\theta = k$ & $\cos\theta = k$.

Tags: trigonometry

My book writes,

> The equation $\sin\theta = k$ is
>   satisfied by two values of $\theta$
>   of the form $\alpha$ &
>   $\pi - \alpha$ in the interval $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Ok. But when I read the result
for $\cos\theta = k$ , then they said

> There are two values of the form $\alpha$ & $-\alpha$ in the interval $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$.

Now,why did the book consider this interval without taking the former ie. of the sine's? What is the cause for this interval?? And why is the interval of cosine not closed unlike that of sine??

Comment: If that is exactly what the book says, then the book is imprecise.  Just think of $\mathrm{sin}(\theta)=-1/2$ or any other value of $k$ between 0 and $-1$.

Comment: Are you sure the book didn't say "the interval $0 \le \theta \le \pi$" for sine?

Comment: @jh4: Sir, the book wrote $2\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two formulas (actually more than two) for the $\cos \theta$

One is $\cos \theta = cos (2\pi - \theta)$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

The other is  $\cos \theta = \cos ( - \theta)$ for $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Both of them cover a period of $2\pi$.

To measure the size of $\alpha$ we need to start from the positive x-axis and :-

For the case of the first formula, one needs to go **anticlockwise** through an angle of $2\pi - \alpha$.

For the case of the second formula, one needs to go **clockwise** through an angle $-\alpha$ (the ‘-‘ also serves as an indication of the direction of travel).

Both traveling methods will give the same target position.